# Making a popup when someone enters the site

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I would like to implement the feature that when someone visits my website, it welcomes them with a popup with two options to choose from (picking their desired language).

It would look something like this:

[image: Desired output]

I'm not sure how I'd go about this, so can someone please let me know how I could go about implementing something like this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), make an attempt at this, then ask a clear question with the problems you encountered and what you need help with. Also change the "java" tag to "javascript" - they are different languages and not related to one another.

Comment: exactly.. Or to help you a little, search for a "simple html modal window".. this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I don't know if it's the best way to do it though.

HTML:

```
<div id="grayout"></div>
<div id="popup">
    <button type="button" id="language1">Language 1</button>
    <button type="button" id="language2">Language 2</button>
</div>
<!-- your page HTML here -->
```

CSS:

```
    #grayout {
        position:fixed;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
    #popup {
        position:fixed;
        height:50%;
        width:50%;
        background-color:white;
        left:25%;
        top:25%;
    }
    #language1 {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:25%;
    }
    #language2 {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        right:25%;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    document.getElementById('language1').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('grayout').style.display = "none";
        //selected language1 code here
    };
    document.getElementById('language2').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('grayout').style.display = "none";
        //selected language2 code here
    };
```